# Android: Recommended workaround for google-drive-sdk timeout issue?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

When a network connection is unavailable, the drive sdk takes a very long time to timeout -- it takes 15 mins according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793218/how-to-set-google-drive-access-timeout-on-android).

I access Drive in an AsynchTask which blocks my application.  So, if there is no network connection, the application shows a ProgressDialog for 15 mins, until the time out.  Possibly I could implement my own timer which kills the AsynchTask after a reasonable duration.  However, it might be difficult to differentiate between a timeout and a lenghty process (like downlaoding a large file on a slow connection) and I would be concenred that there could be issues with the token access not cleaning up properly.  Any suggestions for how to work around  this?

Answer (score 2):

A check if there is a network connection before performing the AsyncTask would help eliminate a lot of the cases, see [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't require an additional permission.  Otherwise, this seems like a smart option.